# CSS 'content' property does not respect color in Chrome on windows, works fine in Mozilla

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome, cross-browser

[image]

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
      .category::before{
        content: "◼";
        margin-right: 0.5em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="category" style="color:red;">Category One</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Plunkr link: https://plnkr.co/edit/FUzEmrbN23ow6gyMAHCf?p=preview
content property not behaving consistently across the browsers.

Comment: Works for me on Chrome

Comment: I opened your plunkr link in Chrome & I can see content in red color in Chrome.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, it is specific to windows, you guys must be using Mac.

Comment: Using hex value for content fixed the issue.